# How can i store image and display it in webpage from database in laravel 4

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

I want to store images in a column of an existing table.And then i want to display it in my webpage.How can i do that? Can anyone help me please.I can store the image path but cant move the image to that folder.So i cant understand how can i display this image in webpage.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better understanding you can follow this link: [storing image in a existing table column and display it using laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906118/storing-image-in-a-existing-table-column-and-display-it-using-laravel-4)

Or follow the below rules

Use a form like below

```
{{ Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-group']) }}
```

For Storing use the below method :

```
$name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('image')->move('public/images',$name);
$destinationPath = '/images/'.$name;
```

And for display it in webpage Do something like below in blade template

```
{{ HTML::image($post->image) }}
```